# How can I check custom Annotation across 2 view models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

So I have the model below and I am trying to create a custom data annotation to validate my data. It is a RequiredIf(). The first argument is the property name, the second argument is what that property name should be equal to.

What I am trying to do is have it look at the QuestionViewModel QuestionType and see if it "text" if so then then this field is required. But I am inside the QuestionOptionViewModel and I am unsure how to create an annotation that will access the QuestionViewModel?

So if you notice below the logic works great at QuestionViewModel. But not when I am inside QuestionOptionViewModel. How can I access a property in another viewmodel in my requiredIf class?

MODELS:

```
  public class QuestionViewModel
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }

            public string QuestionType { get; set; }

            public string SubType { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; set; }

            public int SortOrder { get; set; }

            public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

            [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "radio", ErrorMessage = "Radio Reqired")]
            public int? Selected { get; set; }

            public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }

        }

    public class QuestionOptionViewModel
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; set; }

            [RequiredIf("QuestionType", "text", ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        }
```

CUSTOM DATA ANNOTATION:

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredValue)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            DesiredValue = desiredValue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            Object propertyValue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (propertyValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
                return result;
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "QuestionViewModel.QuestionType"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no way of knowing that even through Reflection.
Consider the following scenario:

```
QuestionViewModel qvm1 = new QuestionViewModel();
QuestionViewModel qvm2 = new QuestionViewModel();

List<QuestionOptionViewModel> qovm = new List<QuestionOptionViewModel>();

qvm1.Options = qovm;
qvm2.Options = qovm;
```

This is the reason why there is no way to get the instance of QuestionViewModel that contain that, because there can be multiple reference of QuestionViewModel pointing to the same List object.